# MVC 4 - Html.Partial() showing System.Namespace text inside DIV (appearing in html on page)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

In my MVC 4 project I'm rendering a partial view inside my `_Layout.chshtml` page. It's inside a drop down menu:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-login>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Account/_LoginPartial.cshtml")
</div>
```

When I run my application and click and the drop down menu, this happens:

[image]

I have other partials rendering and this kind of thing doesn't happen. Any one know why it is happening?

**Partial view**

```
    @model LetLord.Models.LoginModel

@(Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)


@*@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })*@

<input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
<p>
 @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null,
 htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" }) if you don't have an account. </p>

}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: The error is inside your partial view. Please post it. I guess you are missing a `@` somewhere...

Comment: I didn't have @using(Html.BeginForm(...)) - my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your partial view has a slight syntax error:

Change `@(Html.BeginForm` to be `@using(Html.BeginForm`

Comment: I just realised this before you posted - should I still mark this as the answer?

Comment: @MattSull87 If it's the answer, then yeah I would say so :)